# Run command on host

Tags: docker, github, github-actions, volume

I have the following job definition [here](https://github.com/Legion112/discriminator-default-normalizer/blob/90d5e968f78f0c1e0f7fe9b42d4d5d28671c589c/.github/workflows/commit.yml#L75-L75):

```
  run-phpunit:
    needs: [build-image, repository-name]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: /app
    container:
      image: ${{ needs.repository-name.outputs.slug}}/ci:${{github.sha}}
      volumes:
       - ${{github.WORKSPACE}}/.output/:/app/.output
      credentials:
        username: ${{ github.actor }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY_GITHUB }}
```

The mounted volume inside the container own by the `root` user. But my container runs as an `app` user. So it can't write to the mounted directory.

Mounted volume has permission. I want to change permission before running the container to `766` to write to that volume.

How do run a step on the host not inside a container? Basically I wanna do `chmod 766 .output` but not inside container but in host machine.

```
    steps:
      - run: (ls -al)
```

The permission inside container

```
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Nov 30 13:30 .output
-rw-r--r--    1 app      app           1255 Nov 30 13:30 Makefile
```

Answer (score 1):

Github action does not have good support for rootless container execution.

As a solution, I have changed the user of the container to `USER root`.